# Location and filename of most recent BADFILE when using external tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, external-tables

Is there a way to detemine location/filename of latest BADFILE?

When I select from enternal table with BADFILE 'mytable_%a_%p.bad', how do I find out what specific values were %a and %p replaced with?

Or am I stuck with having mytable.bad which I can reliably query and hoping that there will be no race conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states

> %p is replaced by the process ID of the current process. For example,
> if the process ID of the access driver is 12345, then exttab_%p.log
> becomes exttab_12345.log.
>
> %a is replaced by the agent number of the current process. The agent
> number is the unique number assigned to each parallel process
> accessing the external table. This number is padded to the left with
> zeros to fill three characters. For example, if the third parallel
> agent is creating a file and bad_data_%a.bad was specified as the file
> name, then the agent would create a file named bad_data_003.bad.

> If %p or %a is not used to create unique file names for output files
> and an external table is being accessed in parallel, then output files
> may be corrupted or agents may be unable to write to the files.

Having said that, you must remember the purpose of the badfile in the first place.

> The BADFILE clause names the file to which records are written when
> they cannot be loaded because of errors. For example, a record would
> be written to the bad file if a field in the data file could not be
> converted to the data type of a column in the external table. The
> purpose of the bad file is to have one file where all rejected data
> can be examined and fixed so that it can be loaded. If you do not
> intend to fix the data, then you can use the NOBADFILE option to
> prevent creation of a bad file, even if there are bad records.

So the idea ( either for `SQL Loader` or External Tables with access driver `oracle_loader` ) is to have a file to store those records, the bad records, not to trace anything regarding them.

Normally you have external tables associated to text files that you are receiving in a daily/weekly/monthly basis. You store on the badfile those records that can't be read/loaded according to your own table specification.

You use then the `LOGFILE` to find what has happened. Those files are generated in the database directory where the external table is created, and you will have one for each time a badfile needs to be generated.